# 'Add notes' to a Calendar event using Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, script, ical, services

I would like to build a 'Service' for selected text which:

1. Get the currently selected text
2. Creates an Calendar event
3. adds the selected text as a 'note' for that Calendar event

I prefer Automator for creating such workflows. In automator I can use building blocks like:

- `Get Value of Variable`
- `New Calendar Event`

But I have no option to add the selected text as a note to my event.

Is there a way to add notes to an Calendar event using Automator? Or perhaps using the `Run Applescript` or `Run Shell Script` building blocks to achieve this?

[image: Notes in Calendar]